# Code errors at no operator overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, equals-operator

I've got a class using an std::vector> to indicate the item and its count (there can be multiple inventoryitems containing the same item).

I then proceeded to overload the clsInventoryItem its == operator.
The setup ends up being:
clsInventory.cpp -> including: clsInventory.h
clsInventory.h -> including: clsInventoryItem.h
clsInventoryItem.h -> including: stdafx.h (which in turns includes the rest of the project, excluding those 2 header files)

The clsInventoryItem contains the following in its header file:

```
class clsInventoryItem
{
public:
    clsInventoryItem( clsItem* Item, char Quality );
    clsItem* GetItem( );
    char GetQuality( );

    inline bool operator==( const clsInventoryItem& other )
    { /* do actual comparison */
        if (m_Item == other.m_Item
             && m_Quality == other.m_Quality)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
private:
    clsItem* m_Item;
    char m_Quality;
};
```

And it still gives an error that the equals function isn't overloaded ("Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const BrawlerEngineLib::clsInventoryItem' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    BrawlerEngineLib    d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\utility 290 
")...
Anyone knows why this could be the case, and how to potentially solve it?

Comment: ***And it still gives an error that the equals function isn't overloaded*** Please edit your question and add the text of the exact error message. If this is Visual Studio copy the error from the Output Tab.

Comment: You should not include `stdafx.h` from a header. The include of stdafx.h must be the first non comment line of a source file. All lines above `#include "stdafx.h"` are ignored by the compiler.

Comment: `if (m_Item == other.m_Item`  -- You are comparing pointer values.  Surely an `m_Item`'s pointer value should not be used to see if two `clsItem` objects are equal.

Comment: The `bool operator==()` function should be const.

Comment: If you haven't already, ask yourself, "Who is responsible for managing `m_Item`?"

Comment: @drescherjm added the error to the question

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie comparing pointer values is sufficient since it'll be pointing to a list of items loaded from the database, meaning that every item will only be in memory once

Comment: @ProXicT Changed it, doesn't solve the issue :(

Comment: @JoeyvanGangelen Now, after making the function const, it should produce another error, doesn't it? In other words the C2678 error should be gone, right?

Comment: @ProXicT Unfortunately, no... It still gives the same error

Comment: @JoeyvanGangelen Post your code to a pastebin and share the link... The error must be in some other part of your code.

Comment: @ProXicT https://pastebin.com/ndQrjzxx
Not sure how clear it'll be though... First time I've used pastebin

Comment: @JoeyvanGangelen @line 275 there should be the function const, not the return type, change `const inline bool operator==( const clsInventoryItem& other )`  to `bool operator==( const clsInventoryItem& other ) const` (the `inline` keyword is not necessary, new compilers will ignore it)

Comment: @JoeyvanGangelen Also the project does not seem to be working with math, the glm library is way overkill if you use only the `tvec` class from glm.

Comment: @JoeyvanGangelen Something like [this](https://pastebin.com/ZNd4kXaC) should be enough instead of the glm::tvec3. glm lib is quite big...

Comment: There's an entire engine in the project, including math calculations, OpenGL, networking, ... But I imagined uploading 800 MB of a download wasn't exactly what you were looking for ;) I'm trying to get the error to compile, was doing something else inbetween (reverting that now)

Comment: @ProXicT Fixed! :D I wasn't aware that const on the left or right of the function made a difference... Could you post it as an answer so that I can mark it as answer?

Comment: @JoeyvanGangelen Sure, done! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `inline bool operator==(const clsInventoryItem& other)` is expected to be const.
To fix that, you need to change `inline bool operator==(const clsInventoryItem& other)` to `inline bool operator==(const clsInventoryItem& other) const`.

Also, you can get rid off the keyword `inline`, modern compilers will ignore the keyword and older compilers use it as a hint only and decide whether or not to inline the function on their own. They are pretty good at it ;-)

Comment: @JoeyvanGangelen No problem, glad it helped! :-)